# How to import from a module in the root directory?

Tags: python-3.x, python-import

I have the following project structure:

```
root
 |--pkg1
 |   |--__init__.py
 |   |--other_stuff.py
 |--stuff.py
```

In the real project, I also have a tests package in the root directory. 
If I run unit tests with `python -m unittest` at `root`, it works seamlessly.

I want to make the `other_stuff.py` module also executable as a script.
However, if I run it from either `root` or `pkg1` directories, the Python interpreter returns me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pkg1/other_stuff.py", line 1, in <module>
    from stuff import Dummy
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'stuff'
```

Here is the code:

```
# file pkg1/__init__.py
# (empty)


# file pkg1/other_stuff.py
from stuff import Dummy

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # do other stuff
    pass

# file stuff.py
class Dummy:
    pass
```

I also tried the package relative imports `from .stuff` and `from ..stuff`, but it gives the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pkg1/other_stuff.py", line 1, in <module>
    from ..stuff import Dummy
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

I'm not used to the Python3 import system. 
What is the right way to import `stuff.py` in `other_stuff.py` to make it work both in the tests and as a script?

Answer (score -1):

I have found a solution that might not be the best, but it worked.
To run `other_stuff.py` as a script, I just need to open the terminal in the `root` directory and run `python3 -m pkg1.other_stuff`.

Comment: do you have Github?

Comment: I saw you asked a question about `Badges` in `JavaFX` that are similar to `Bootstrap` `Badge`.